# MIT 6.042J, Lec 2: Induction

Tags: induction

Question: Prove that a 2^n x 2^n courtyard can be tiled using L-shaped tiles of size 3 with a statue in the middle. (Use the Induction axiom) [Click here to view the original question](https://youtu.be/z8HKWUWS-lA?t=3557)

What I want to know is, can't we just nest a square of size 2^n x 2^n on which the inductive hypothesis has been applied in the centre of a square of size 2^(n+1) x 2^(n+1)? In that case, p(n) => p(n+1), right? Meaning every subsequent block up to n+1 will have a statue in the centre.

I'm sorry if the way I phrased the questions isn't right.

Comment: If you put four $4\times 4$ squares together, each with statue near the middle, you will have an $8\times8$ square with four separated statues when you only want one statue

Comment: `[[# ,# ,# ,#]
 [# ,* ,S ,#]
 [# ,* ,*, #]
 [# ,# ,#, #]]`

This is what I meant. n = 2, which means the 2 x 2 square with a statue in its middle(i.e., the 2^0 x 2^0 square('S')) is in the middle of the 2^2 x 2^2 square. (Just view the nested list in 2d for clarification). I didn't mean 4 4x4 squares, I meant just one in the middle of the 8x8 square.